# Check overall progress made in a git repository

Tags: git, version-control, diff, git-diff

There's a git repository which I'd like to "monitor". There's a lot going on in it, new branches, old ones going away either bc merged or abandoned, tags, push -f, GC, so on. I clone it at some point in time and then after a bit of time, I'd like to get an overall picture of things that have happened in the repository. (Obviously, I don't need intermediate stages, just comparing the two DAG snapshots.)

I'm happy to create a new clone and compare it with the previous one if needed, but somehow, I'd like to see some sort of a readable diff of the two DAGs. What'd be a good way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of Git is to make our developer's life easier by preventing operations such as a "manually hard-"copying two versions of code in order to compare them. This is true for comparing commits but also for branches.

Git lists many UI software in the page [GUI Clients](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis). It can only recommend you to make your choose one depending on how you like the information to be displayed. You'll have to take some time understanding the UI software. I personally used Git Extensions:

[image: https://gitextensions.github.io/images/commitlog205.png]

The branches and commits are both displayed in the main view. And it's easy to have a quick look at the changes between one commit and another.

Comment: Question was about comparing two *repositories* not two commits or branches.